# Windows 7 Pro with Windows 8.1 Pro license?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, downgrade

The company I work for will be replacing a group of computers with new.  With the pending return of the normal start menu, I'd like to start looking to Windows 8.1 as a viable OS option for the future.   However, with that not being an option right now I was wondering, will we be able to (legally) install Windows 7 Pro with Windows 8.1 Pro licenses?

Comment: Looks like the same question/answer to me!  I did a search, but didn't have the "downgrade" keyword so I didn't find anything relevant.

Comment: You should have downgrade rights if your company holds a volume license for Windows 8.1 Pro or Enterprise, or if the computers shipped with Windows 8.1 Pro preinstalled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDF: [Downgrade rights for Microsoft Volume Licensing, OEM, and full-package product licenses](http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/8/9/68964284-864d-4a6d-aed9-f2c1f8f23e14/Downgrade_Rights.pdf)

> What are the downgrade rights for Windows 8.1? For Windows 8.1
>   licenses acquired though an OEM, you may downgrade to the equivalent
>   edition for Windows 7 and  Windows Vista. For Windows 8.1 licenses
>   acquired though Volume Licensing, you may downgrade to any prior
>   version  of the licensed Windows edition. Refer to the table below for
>   more specific product downgrade rights.

[image]

Or Use: [Classic Shell](http://www.classicshell.net/)

[image: Windows 8 Classic menu Windows 7]

Comment: Thanks a ton for the info, STTR!  I appreciate it.  I'd look at Classic Shell, but I'd rather not have a 3rd party software doing what Windows should be.  I think we'll be going towards the Windows 8.1 licenses.  I would upvote ya, but I don't have the rep to do so yet.

Thanks again!

Comment: @JeremyT maybe this help too: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askpfeplat/archive/2013/10/17/exploring-windows-8-1-start-screen-and-start-button-options-and-configurations.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is pretty much, yes. But you'll have to find your own license key that works: see here http://www.microsoft.com/OEM/en/licensing/sblicensing/Pages/what_to_do_downgrade_rights.aspx#fbid=xrXYPuTS8PM

You'd be better buying the new machines with the Windows 7 downgrade option.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.